# Is there any way to find the C# code that is created from XAML with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Given some Xaml like this:

```
<headingView:HeadingView
    x:Class="Test.Views.Decks.DeckBase.DeckMgmt.DeckMgmtPage2"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:headingView="clr-namespace:Test.Templates.Pages.HeadingView;assembly=Test"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Test.Templates"
    BackIconVisible="True"
    PageTitle="Mgmt">
    <t:Stack>

        <t:ContentFrame Heading="Reset">
            <t:LinkGrid TapCommand="{Binding ResetDeckCmd}" Text1="Reset" />
        </t:ContentFrame>

        <t:ContentFrame Heading="Sort">
            <t:LinkGrid Text1="Sort" />
        </t:ContentFrame>

    </t:Stack>
</headingView:HeadingView>
```

I don't need help in changing this to C# but I would like to know if there is any place or way I can find out the intermediate C# that is created?

Comment: look for `*.xaml.g.cs` files that are generated by the XAML complier in your project folders

Comment: The only thing that's there is in your project folder -> obj -> debug -> netstandard2.0 and then the <filename>.xaml.g.cs files (g is for generated). Not sure if that's what you're after

Comment: In case you fall here developing already using Maui: *.xaml.g.cs are no more generated for xaml

Answer (score 3):

Viewing the actual code generated by the compiler is tricky (I tried for a couple of hours but I could not find a way to directly view the code) - but it is possible to view the source code itself.

First of all - download .NET reflector and the appropriate Visual Studio extension.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

[image]

Now we need to find the method that we want to decompile.

The method `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml()` is found in your page's `xaml.g.cs` file. According to Microsoft:

*When Visual Studio builds a project containing a XAML file, it [the method] parses the XAML file to generate a C# code file (for example, MainPage.xaml.g.cs) that contains the definition of the InitializeComponent method:*

The method in this case is the `LoadFromXaml()` method.

Now add a breakpoint like so:

[image]

Press `F12` until you reach the following:

You will reach the 'Load' method:
[image]

You will see something like this:

[image]

From here - you can browse the rest of the `XamlLoader` class's source code:

[image]

Very interesting, isn't it? This is the closest thing to a solution that I got to.

I've just shared it as an image as I don't think it would be appropriate to share the full code as a code snippet.

It's not exactly what you're looking for - but I still hope this helped answer your question either way.